# Svcutil.exe generates wrong method types

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

WCF novice here.
In my solution i have 3 projects:

1. Common Logic
2. Client
3. Server

Both `Client` and `Server` imports `Common Logic`.

My server has a method called `GetNextFile`. Here the interface implementation:

```
[OperationContract]
RemoteFileInfo GetNextFile(GUIDSetting GUID);
```

Here what `RemoteFileInfo` and `GUIDSetting` looks like:

```
[MessageContract]
public class GUIDSetting
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Guid;
}

[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string Status;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And here a snippet of the actual implementation:

```
public RemoteFileInfo GetNextFile(GUIDSetting GUIDRequested)
{
    //stuff
    return result;
}
```

When i use svcutil to generate my proxy i use this parameters:

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8001/MyService/
```

but that `GetNextFile` method in generated proxy looks like this:

```
public string GetNextFile(string Guid, out long Length, out string Status, out System.IO.Stream FileByteStream)
{
    //stuff
}
```

and this is the generated Async method:

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RemoteFileInfo> IServiceFileStream.GetNextFileAsync(GUIDSetting request)
{
    return base.Channel.GetNextFileAsync(request);
}
```

Why is this happening? I can try to figure out why I have `Lenght`, `Status` and `Stream` as `out` parameters, but where is `fileName`? And why the Async method have correct parameters (**RemoteFileInfo** and **GUIDSetting**)? I need those parameters on my sync function but I have no idea how to achieve it and why svcutils.exe gives me this output

Comment: well, this is one of those situation when the comment is actually a solution, it worked! If you post it as a answer I can mark it as solution! Thank you, i really need to study WCF to better understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specifically need to control how the SOAP structure is composed, then try to use DataContract instead of MessageContract.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class GUIDSetting
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Guid;
}
```